Getting rectangular crop from GeoTIFF using GDAL
I cannot get my head around this problem:
I have a georeferenced image in EPSG:25832. If I open it in QGIS, it aligns perfectly. I now need a cutout from it. this cutout is a polygon (GeoJSON in EPSG:4326).
To get the cutout I use gdalwarp and do this:
gdalwarp -cutline [geojson] -crop_to_cutline.

That actually crops the image as I would expect it - at least when I open it in QGIS (it aligns perfectly).
Now when I open it in a non-GIS application like a normal picture viewer, I get an image with slight white bounds:

It is somehow correct, but what I want is, that the image would be pixel-straight without any white borders. - so the first colorful pixel on the top left should be image pixel 0,0, (currently ~5,0) and the last one on the bottom right should be 512/512 so it should be reprojected again? Is there anything I can do with GDAL to get a (basically not georeferenced anymore) straight image back?
I also tried to not use gdalwarp, but instead use gdal_transform and then the srcwin (not projwin) option to extract a pixel-perfect image, that works, without the white borders, but then the content is not correct anymore.
So I think going for gdalwarp is the correct way, but as I said, I want to have the output not georeferenced anymore but as a straight x y pixel image without the white borders.

There is a rotation between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:25832 and therefore the vertical-horizontal rectangle in EPSG:4326 is slightly rotated in EPSG:25832. You do not see the bounds in QGIS because it renders them as transparent but standard image viewer does not. Crop the image with a box that is in EPSG:25832. With "box" I mean the envelope of the EPSG:4326 polygon after it has been repeojected into EPSG:25832. Another way to reach the zero rotation is to cut with a EPSG:4326 polygon and warp the result also into EPSG:4326 with gdalwarp, but the image will look stretched.

Hi, thanks a lot! i have solved the problem simply by first warping the source image to pseudomercator. then i can use a 4326 geojson to trim out my rectangle. in the end i resize the image to what i originally wanted to have

Right, those to systems have the same orientation so your workaround is OK.

@user30184, please put your magnificent comment as a valid answer !
